# How to display messages in notification format like WhatsApp, when app is in background for chatting application on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing a chat application like WhatsApp. We are using our own API with our own database server for sending and receiving messages. It is working perfect.

Now, the receiver and the sender should get the notification alert whenever they receive messages from each other if their apps is not opened.

It became a big task to me to accomplish. I'm unable to get the notification alert. I tried to use Firebase, but still I don't understand, what are requirements I need to give (Tokens, Keys).

Please, let me know if I need to change any data in my server side and is there any possibility to integrate from my server to Firebase and if it is possible then what are the parameters I need to integrate/send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maintain status of each user , like when app opens make them online and onDestroy() make update status to offline , if user is offline send both message and notification where as if user is online send only message....

Comment: So if user is in offline, how can I display notification?

Comment: @Ram if the user in chat page then no need to send notification just send message , if user exits chat page but app is still open then send both message and notification, try use a flag so that it will be easy to handle

Comment: For suppose receiver is in offline, how can I display message in notification format?

Comment: Is it mandatory to use Firebase for showing messages in notification format?

Comment: may in notification onReceive send flags also , if active show notification else need to show

Comment: yes without using firebase we cannot send notification

Comment: For sending status to server which method is better `onDestroy()` or `isDestroyed()` ?

Comment: @Ram use onDestroy()

Comment: Thank You. Can you please help me for running API in separate class and declare in `MainActivity.java`.